# How do you invert the current selection?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have a document  of 10 lines and I have a line selected.
How do I invert the selection so that instead, all the other lines are selected?

I searched and searched, could not find anything on this!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible but what is your goal with this? What do you want to do with the other 9 lines?

Comment: @Seth  A..a..are you sure?!! but how can that be?! This is a common command in general software. Its available on Sublime Text and many other generic softwares! even my choice of file manager and file explorer itself has it. This cant be.  I have no perticular use for it now. but I have been constantly looking for it past weeks.

Comment: As I wrote, I don't know whenever it is possible or not. There is a whole lot of software where it's not available, that I am sure of. You could always just use an [extension like selection extended by Sreenivas Alapati](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cg-cnu.vscode-selection-extended). I still wonder what the usecase is though as you have been looking for a feature you don't need.

Comment: I will look into that extension, thanks!

Comment: @Seth Simple sample use case: refactoring a bunch of statically made HTML code into separate modules (i.e. extracting menus, headers, etc from designer-provided pages). Once the templates are done, then it's a simple operation to go through every page, get into the "meat" div, `shift+alt+right arrow` until the main div is selected, invert selection, and hit delete. Though of course the workaround is simple -- hit `ctrl+x`, `ctrl+a`, `delete`, `ctrl+v`. But "invert selection" would be more orthodox (and has been historically available in most editors).